# "ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement" when using simple loop insert

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql

**Summary**

I'm trying to insert two rows into a simple table having two var_char columns,
but it ends up with "ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement" pointing to the part `FOR loop_counter IN 1..2`.

**What I've tried**

Followed the description at https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/for_loop.php
Checked internet for similar problems, but it looks like the problem is rather exotic.

**The code**

```
FOR loop_counter IN 1..2
LOOP
    INSERT INTO table_a
        (COLUMN_ONE, COLUMN_TWO)
    Values
        ('value_one', 'value_two');
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing BEGIN END, learn more about anonymous block [here](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-anonymous-block/)

```
BEGIN
   FOR loop_counter IN 1 .. 2
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO table_a
         (column_one
         ,column_two)
      VALUES
         ('value_one'
         ,'value_two');
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```